# How to make sure you call pip only in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

How to prevent accidentally calling pip when I am not in a virtualenv?

I wrote the following script called `pip`and added it to my `~/bin` (which is before pip in my `$PATH`):

```
# This script makes sure I don't accidentally install pip without virtualenv
# This script requires $PIP to be set to the absolute path of pip to execute pip
# if $PIP is not set, it will write a message
if [ -z "$PIP" ]; then
   echo "you are not in a virtual env"
   echo "use virtual env or"
   # propose the second item in $PATH
   echo "  export PIP="`type -ap pip|sed -n 2p`
   echo "to cleanup use"
   echo "  unset PIP"
else
    # execute pip
    exec $PIP "$@"
fi
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Checking `which pip` each time is not an option, right?

Comment: You mean checking ```which pip``` on the command line each time before I run pip?

Comment: Yup, just first thing that came into my mind.

Comment: The problem is that I simply forget checking and this script is a reminder for myself to make sure I am in a virtualenv or call pip explicitly outside the virtualenv...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd recommend putting this in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

and you can also add the following function to your `~/.bashrc` that allows you to explicitly call pip outside of a virtual environment if you so choose:

```
gpip() {
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
```

Now you can still use your global pip version for doing things like upgrading virtualenv:

```
gpip install --upgrade pip virtualenv
```

Comment: I know I have replied to an old question, but I came here looking for a solution to the same question and the other answers here weren't enough for me. Now that I have "solved" my problem, I have added my solution here to hopefully benefit others in the same situation.

Answer (score 9):

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```